# how to launch exe file without giving path in java

Tags: java

I want to use

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("arduino.exe");
```

instead of

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\progrm files\\Arduino\\arduino.exe");
```

Comment: Does it work when you have that exe in your Windows `PATH` ? But: what's the real reason why you don't want to hardcode the complete path ?

Comment: For this your exe file should be in same folder of jar file.

Comment: @Prabhav I don't think Windows takes kindly to exe files inside jar files. You'll first need to extract it to a temporary location to execute it, if you ship it inside a jar file.

Comment: suppose i installed  5 new application and i dont want to copy paste all exe file into jar file @Prabhav

Comment: I am not saying inside jar, I am saying if your exe file is in X directory than put jar in same directory X so we do not need to specify absolute path

Comment: if some one change my path where arduino app stored so i dont want to fixed my app path @Marged

Comment: i understood @Prabhav...my point is i already created 5 button using jsp and read it jsp to Servlet..so in servlet instread of giving full path i just want to directly write any app name and it will have to open

Comment: @KartikLukhi Either your java app use a fixed path, use the windows path, or your java app scan the system to locale Arduino (either file system or registry system; both may change with future Arduino versions). There is no silver bullet.

Comment: But you have to mention path somewhere. if you can not put exe in relative location.

Comment: Other wise you have to write code to find file with app name and execute it. but it will be dengerus.

Comment: correct @Sheepy...Is there any module or method where i can write any exe file name and it will give me full path where exe file stored in my system

Comment: can you plz help me out to how to find file in my system @Prabhav

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/dir_search_file.htm

Comment: But this approch will be risky if you have multiple exe with same name you may end up with executing wrong file.

Comment: That was again fixed path(C drive) @Prabhav....if i install new app and save it into D drive then?

Comment: You have to at least mention root dir from where you want to start the search. Above link shows just example. you have to modify code by mentioning all of your drives.

Comment: I recommend you keep fix directory where you can put all of the exe app. execute them by passing file name ex. Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runtime.exec(exePath+"/arduino.exe");

Comment: thankiuu @Prabhav..above link code worked fine

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Many apps simply have a configuration option where they allow user to pick the external `exe` file the app needs. Eclipse does exactly that, for example. That is if you don't want to package the `exe` with you app JAR file.

Comment: @KartikLukhi, please don't search entire file systems to find a single file you need. Just have a user tell you where it is. Save it into a `.properties` file somewhere for future keeping. Scanning the whole disk is a sure way your app gets shut down as suspicious, not to mention that you are wasting time of your users and resources of your machine doing the search.

Comment: now i am quite confused..suppose my 2 exe file stored in C drive and another 2 exe files stored in D drive... what should i do if  i want to write a java code to open these four file without using path and without saving there four exe files into jar and .properties?

Comment: if any one explain with code then that will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To execute file java first need to locate it. If it is not in the relative path of jar than you have to specify the path. otherwise, java will not know which file to execute.

You can make that path configurable according to your requirement.
Evry project has fix structure of its resources so you can decide structure and code accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this, its required that you put your .exe file in same directory where your .jar file is stored. Otherwise you will have to specify either relative or absolute path.

Comment: If you don't specify an absolute path, it will be taken relative to the *current working directory*, which is not linked to the location of the jar file that is being executed. So putting it in the same directory as where your jar file is stored in no way guarantees that you can execute it like "arduino.exe"